# why six packs are in front of protruded stomach?

Tags: stomach

I used to do abdomen exercise daily. As a result I got some strong muscles under the skin. But still my stomach is protruded like something filled in it like air or water.

Please suggest some tips to reduce it.

Comment: Do you feel bloated?
If so, it's possible you have some food intolerance

Comment: So, you're saying that you have a six-pack and yet, your stomach is big?

Comment: yes...you are right

Comment: I didn't even know that that's possible. Are you sure it's a six-pack? And it's visible?

Comment: I got cuttings...in front..but there belly...stomach is projected...

Comment: I'm not certain I'm familiar with that concept; however, as long as it's not an infection, all you need to do is reduce your food portion and eat healthy. Over time, your stomach size will reduce because of the reduced portions.

Comment: @PrasoonPrahaladan I have the same thing. If I flex my abs I get a flat stomach and look really ripped. If I let go and have a normal stomach, it comes out as if I'd have fat ... but it's a 6 pack of abs instead. Do you have a concave chest (Pectus Excavatum)  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pectus_excavatum?

Answer (score 2):

You may have problems with posture. Check if you dont have a case of hyperlordosis. People with hyperlordosis have their lower back muscles picnched too tightly, causing the pelvis to tilt forward, stretching the abdomen and making it stand out and look round, regardless of the amounts of fat on it.

Its hard to say if this is your case, especially without o photo, you should see a physical therapist.

Answer (score 1):

There are two likely hypotheses.

1. Visceral fat.
2. Massive abdominal and lower back muscles.

If it's visceral fat, chances are you can't do anything about it without hitting underfat levels. If it's massive abdominal and lower back muscles, I would suggest you cherish these and consider seriously picking up powerlifting. It's possible to have your body decimate muscles, but it's such a waste.